# How to output multiple values with the same key in reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a bunch of text files which are categorized and I would like to create a sequence file for each category in which the key is the category name and the value consists of all the textual content of all the files for the category.

I have a nosql database which has only two columns. Each row represents a file, the first column is the category name and the second one is the absolute address of the text file stored on the HDFS. My mapper reads the database and output pairs in which the key is the category and the value is the absolute address. In the reducer sides, I have the addresses of all the files for each category and I would like to create one sequence files for each category in which the key is the category name and the value consists of the all textual content of all the files belonging to that category.

A simple solution is to iterate through the pairs (in the reducer) and open files one by one and append their content to a String variable and at the end create a sequence file using `MultipleOutputs`. However as the file sizes may be large appending the content to a single String may not be possible. Is there any way to do this without using a String variable?

Comment: As I can understand, in reducer you have category as key and list is the addresses of the files who has content. Am I right. As you know, number of reducers is the number of unique keys. So you have a category and a list of addresses in reducer. Let me know, if I am correct

Comment: yes that is correct and I'd like to output one sequence file per key.

Answer (score 0):

Then, since you have all the files in reducer, you can get the content of those files, and append using StringBuilder to save memory, and then discard that StringBuilder reference. If avoiding String is your question, StringBuilder is a quick way. The IO operaion involving the file access and reading is resource intensive. However the data itself, should be ok given the architecture of reducers in hadoop.

You can also think of using a combiner. However, that is mainly used to reduce the traffic between map and reduce. You can take advantage of preparing part of the sequence file, at combiner and then remaining at reducer level. ofcouse this is valid only if the content can be added as it comes and not based on specific order.

Comment: My concern is memory issue in the reducer. That is, let's say the text files be quite large, then I will run into memory issues even if I user StringBuilder? Right? IS there any way to flush out the value into disk partially when it reaches a specific size?

Comment: Flushing might not work, because you requirement is atomic at reducer level for each category. Once your are in reducer, you have IO operation, appending each file content into String/StringBUilder, and then wrting sequence file. You can increase number of reducers to perform the job faster. You can give it a try and not the statistics(memory usage and execution time). If it still takes more memory, then you can think or a job before this to set up the data and then create sequence file.